# Grass seed or sod?

Tags: grass, yard

My yard is heavily shaded and was neglected by the previous owners. I removed a heavy covering of dead leaves and have no grass.

I am in N. Alabama. There 2 large oak trees at the front of the lot and  there is about 30' between the trees and my house. The house faces North.

What type of grass seed or sod would work best in the shade?

Comment: it will help us all provide a better answer if you can provide a few more details, such as your geographic location (not address, just region), climatic zone, type of shade (trees or buildings), soil type if you are aware. Also a photo is always very helpful but not essential. To add this information, please EDIT your original question rather than add comments.

Comment: Is the area in shade the whole year round? and what is creating the shade?

Comment: I have found that mosses work well in shade.

Comment: @andrewbuilder Solid advice. I would just add this fun tip for you, you can surround the word edit in square brackets (`[edit]`) and it will create an [edit] link for the OP to click on.